# Modal de materialize no abre en hosting

Tags: php, mysql, html5, modal, materialize

te agradezco por entrar!
Sucede que todo lo que esté dentro del while desaparece, si tengo un boton dentro del while y otro fuera del while, solo se muestra el que esta fuera del while, este es el codigo que tengo:

El HTML es este:

```
<?php
  include("php/conexion.php");
  while($v = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
<li class="dropdown3"><a href="#modal<?php echo $v['id'] ?>" class="modal-trigger"><?php echo $v['titulo'] ?></a></li>
<?php
  }
?>
```

El PHP:

```html
<?php
    $host_name = 'asd';
 $database = 'db7185617051';
 $user_name = 'dbo7185617051';
 $password = 'dsa';
 $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
 } else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM informacion";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
 }
?>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Aja y que quieres que hagamos con verlo en tu web?, deberias postear codigo que usas para llamar a esa libreria. Quiza en tu hosting no este encontrando la ruta de la libreria.

Comment: ahi lo edite...

Comment: Intenta poner $('#modal2') en lugar de $('#modal')

Comment: Ahi intente pero es lo mismo, me funcionan todos los modales menos este que se conecta con la bd.

Comment: estan cargando las librerias de bootstrap y jquery bien en la pagina remota

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto en tu js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnTriggerModal").on("click", function() { //Agrega un ID a tu botón
            $('.modal').modal();
            $('#modal2').modal('open');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, igual sigue sucediendo lo mismo, como aclare en la publicación, deduzco que el problema viene del lado de php o mysql.

Comment: Pero no pusiste el ID en tu botón que lanza el pop up "btnTriggerModal"

Comment: Sube el código de conexion.php, cambia los accesos por unos temporales.

Comment: Ahí subi el contenido del archivo.

Comment: Te estas conectando a una base de datos remota verdad? te estaba pidiendo ese código para ver tu cadena de conexión, ya que efectivamente el error esta en el php  y no carga el código del modal2

Comment: no, la base de datos está en el mismo hosting, utilizo 1&1. El host de la DB es: db718561705.db.1and1.com

Comment: Pero cuando desarrollas de forma local, se supone que estas conectándote de forma remota a la base de datos o sino estas usando una bd local y si este es el caso la cadena de  conexión no estaría correcta a menos que la cambies en cada upload. Sospecho que ese es el caso porque sólo te funciona de forma local.

Comment: de forma local no me puedo conectar a la bd del hosting, pero ahi si me tira el error correspondiente de que no se pudo realizar la conexión, de forma local uso una bd local. Tengo 2 conexiones distintas para el local y para el hosting.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asignar el mismo `id` a varios elementos, los `id` deben ser únicos no se pueden repetir. Dentro del `while` siempre generas el el mismo `ìd` por lo que que cada modal que se genera repite el `id`:

```
<?php
  include("php/conexion.php");
  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
<div id="modal2" class="modal">
  ...
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Podrías generar el link y el modal a la vez:

```
<?php
  include("php/conexion.php");
  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal<?= $fila['id'] ?>">Modal <?= $fila['id'] ?></a>

<div id="modal<?= echo $fila['id'] ?>" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content info-modal">
      <img class="info-img" src="img.jpg">
      <h3 class="info-title"><?php echo $fila['titulo'] ?></h3>
      <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
          <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">touch_app</i>¿Qué es esto?</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['que-es'] ?></span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">help</i>¿Para que sirve?</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['para-que-sirve'] ?></span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">build</i>¿Cómo se usa?</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['como-se-usa'] ?></span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i>Más comandos</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['mas-comandos'] ?></span></div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">burst_mode</i>Más imágenes</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['imagenes'] ?></span></div>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="https://discord.gg/Gq8pjvc" target="_blank" class="modal-action modal-close deep-orange darken-2 white-text waves-effect waves-green btn-flat tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Soporte en el canal de Discord">Tengo un problema</a>
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close green darken-1 white-text waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">¡Gracias! :D</a>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
 }
?>
```

Quedando algo así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal 1</a>

  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content info-modal">
        <img class="info-img" src="img.jpg">
        <h3 class="info-title">modal 1</h3>
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">touch_app</i>¿Qué es esto?</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['que-es'] ?></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">help</i>¿Para que sirve?</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['para-que-sirve'] ?></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">build</i>¿Cómo se usa?</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['como-se-usa'] ?></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i>Más comandos</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['mas-comandos'] ?></span></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">burst_mode</i>Más imágenes</div>
                <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['imagenes'] ?></span></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="https://discord.gg/Gq8pjvc" target="_blank" class="modal-action modal-close deep-orange darken-2 white-text waves-effect waves-green btn-flat tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Soporte en el canal de Discord">Tengo un problema</a>
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close green darken-1 white-text waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">¡Gracias! :D</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal2">Modal 2</a>

    <div id="modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content info-modal">
    <img class="info-img" src="<?php echo $fila['img'] ?>">
    <h3 class="info-title">modal 2</h3>
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">modal2</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['que-es'] ?></span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">help</i>¿Para que sirve?</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['para-que-sirve'] ?></span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">build</i>¿Cómo se usa?</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['como-se-usa'] ?></span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">dvr</i>Más comandos</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['mas-comandos'] ?></span></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">burst_mode</i>Más imágenes</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $fila['imagenes'] ?></span></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="https://discord.gg/Gq8pjvc" target="_blank" class="modal-action modal-close deep-orange darken-2 white-text waves-effect waves-green btn-flat tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Soporte en el canal de Discord">Tengo un problema</a>
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close green darken-1 white-text waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">¡Gracias! :D</a>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
      $('.modal').modal();
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en el momento que incluyo al botón que abre el modal dentro del `while`, ya deja de responder lo anterior, es decir el botón que abre el sideNav que contiene al botón que abre el modal. Todo lo que incluyo dentro del while desaparece.

Comment: @GabrielBenitez ¿Lo estas incluyendo dentro del `while` pero fuera del modal? es raro, edita  la pregunta y añade como tienes el código actualmente.

Comment: Ahi lo edite, nuevamente muchas gracias por ayudarme!

Comment: @GabrielBenitez por lo que veo estas metiendo todo el menu dentro del `while` por lo que esto te dara problemas con los id, ademas de repetir el menu innecesariamente, aparte de que el `<li>` debe encerrar al `<a href...>` no al reves. Puedes poner los id a mano si los conoces, sin necesidad de incluir el link en el while.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, hice lo que dijiste, me quedo el html un poco más ordenado, sin embargo el problema sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿qué no se ve el enlace? ¿qué no abre el modal? no se en que punto estamos ahora mismo, para audarte. Hice algunas pruebas y funciona. ¿Puedes ponen un ejemplo de tu tabla en la base de datos?

Comment: El problema es que lo que esté dentro del while no aparece cuando cargo la página, si dejo un boton afuera del while y otro adentro del while, el que esta adentro no aparece.

Comment: @GabrielBenitez Pero dentro del while en que parte por que lo veo es que esta dentro de la lista, por lo que se deberia mostrar en esa lista. ¿o el resto de elementos `<li>` tampoco se muestran? revisa que no estes aplicando algun estilo css que esconda los elementos

Comment: Ahi edite la publicación para que veas

Comment: Te voto positivo para que alcances reputacion y podamos [continuar en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72183/discussion-between-xerif-and-gabriel-benitez).