# ¿Por qué no carga un modal con PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, materialize

Bienvenidos, gracias por ingresar.
Mi problema es que hay un solo modal en la página que no funciona, todos los otros funcionan bien. Este modal tiene que mostrar información extraída de una base de datos, pero a la hora de apretar el botón que abre el modal, en la consola de Chrome me sale un error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que es un error de PHP o de la BD, ya que de forma local la página funciona correctamente, hasta cargando la información de la BD local y todo. Les dejo mi PHP y SQL para ver si encuentran algún defecto.

PHP (conexion.php):

```html
<?php
    $host_name = 'db718561705.db.1and1.com';  
    $database = 'db718561705';
    $user_name = 'dbo718561705';
    $password = '*********';
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM informacion";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
    }
?>
```

SQL (phpMyAdmin):

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.14.8
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: db718561705.db.1and1.com
-- Tiempo de generación: 13-01-2018 a las 12:03:01
-- Versión del servidor: 5.5.58-0+deb7u1-log
-- Versión de PHP: 5.4.45-0+deb7u11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `db718561705`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `informacion`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `informacion` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `titulo` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `que-es` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `para-que-sirve` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `como-se-usa` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `mas-comandos` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `imagenes` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `informacion`
--

INSERT INTO `informacion` (`id`, `img`, `titulo`, `que-es`, `para-que-sirve`, `como-se-usa`, `mas-comandos`, `imagenes`) VALUES
(1, 'img/2.jpg', 'Biomas/Survival', 'es balbla', 'sirvepara blalba', 'se usa bla', 'comandos', '<img class="info-img" src="img/2.jpg">');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Mejor muestranos también el modal en cuestión y como lo llamas.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130508/modal-de-materialize-no-abre-en-hosting
Ya me intentaron ayudar con eso pero no es eso.

Comment: Sinceramente el error que te da nada tiene que ver con PHP, basicamente te dice que no encuentra o no puede leer la propiedad `M_Modal`